# Display multiple rows in Thymeleaf table

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a table of attendees of my event using Thymeleaf on a Spring Boot app.

My table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered tabl-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="tempEvent : ${event}">
            <td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees[event].firstName}" />
            <td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees[event].lastName}" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I just use a single td with `<td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees}" />` I get this:

```
[EventAttendees [id=1, firstName=Paul, lastName=Jones], EventAttendees [id=2, firstName=Luke, lastName=Smyth]
```

This output contains the correct data. The above table however only outputs my second attendee(Luke Smyth). If I change the td lines to:

```
<td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees[0].firstName}" />
<td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees[0].lastName}" />
```

or

```
<td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees[1].firstName}" />
<td th:text="${tempEvent.clubEventAttendees[1].lastName}" />
```

The correct person is displayed depending on their position. How can I change my table to display any attendees that get returned?

This is my Event model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="club_events")
public class Event {
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="clubEvent",
            cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<EventAttendees> clubEventAttendees;

    // define fiends
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name="date_time")
    private LocalDate dateTime;
    
    public Event() {
        
    }

    public Event(int id, String name, String location, String description, LocalDate dateTime) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.description = description;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

This is my EventAttendees model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="club_event_attendees")
public class EventAttendees {
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="club_event_id")
    private Event clubEvent;

    // define fiends
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="mobile")
    private String mobile;
    
    public EventAttendees() {
        
    }

    public EventAttendees(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String mobile, int clubEventId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

}
```

Note: getters and setters have been removed.

I currently have a page which lists all events(in a table):
[image]

The Attendees column will be removed once I get this figured out but if the View Attendees button is clicked I'd like to be taken to a page containing a similar table but with the firstName, lastName, phone and mobile of all attendees. Basically, I'd like to take the data returned in clubEventAttendees and display it in a table similar to the table above.

Comment: You need to add your model to see what are the variable types

Comment: Could you elaborate bit more on what you actually want to display? Is it all `clubEventAtendess` from `event` what you want to display? If you could provide example of how the response should look like

Comment: @Prebiusta I added some detail to the bottom of my question.

Comment: What would I do in this case, I would create `<a th:href="@{'/event/' + ${tempEvent.id} + '/attendees'}">View Attendees</a>` and somwhere in controller I would write `@GetMapping("/event/{eventId}/attendees")`. In this controller method I would access databsae and fetch users for given event ID in Path Variable, and returned new template HTML file. Would this be something you want to achieve? I could write an example

Comment: Yes, that sounds pretty much what I want.

Comment: Let me write some code example and I will get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so as promised, here is the code.

I can explain the example with `Person` and `Car`. The idea is that `Person` has `List<Car>`.

[image: You can see Person details in the picture]

After pressing on *View Cars*, a new page is opened, where you see a list of Cars.

[image: Example of Car list]

How to achieve this is fairly simple. When rendering `List<Person>` from modelAttribute `people`, you can use the following code

```
<tr th:each="person : ${people}">
                <td th:text="${person.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${person.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${person.lastName}"></td>
                <td>
                    <a th:href="@{'/person/' + ${person.id} + '/cars'}">View Cars</a>
                </td>
</tr>
```

Href from `th:href="@{'/person/' + ${person.id} + '/cars'}"` executed following method in controller

```
@GetMapping("/person/{personId}/cars")
public String getCars(Model model, @PathVariable Integer personId){
    model.addAttribute("cars", carRepository.findAllByPersonId(personId));
    return "web/car-list";
}
```

after which a new template is rendered. I uploaded source code on GitHub, it can be found here https://github.com/Prebiusta/thymeleaf-playground

Hope it helps, let me know if there is something else.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for taking the time to get that for me. It's much appreciated.